# Отключить масштабирование при клике на плеер html5 (mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

На сайте установлен плеер от uppod html5, с компьютера все работает хорошо, а с телефона при клике на плеер появляется белое всплывающее окно. Необходимо его отключить. Окно появляется в мобильной версии google chrome, а в опере сам плеер масштабируется при клике. Пробовал задать в css "cod{max-height:999999px;max-width:999999px;}" - не помогает. А также пробовал отключать все скрипты.

Скрин
[image: скрин сайта с проблемой]